# secustom title and description at shared video on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, youtube, facebook-opengraph

I want to share youtube video on facebook and want to allow to play this video directly on wall Also i want to put there my custom title and description. For the purposes i created meta tags for my page:

```html
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
  <meta property="og:type"        content="video.movie" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVHfkVKgf2M" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content=" Make a Website With Joomla 3.4 - 2016 (Windows)" />
```

It works almost well becides it puts title and description from youtube tags but not from my custom title and description. Any idea how to reach necessary functionality?
Thanks.